# has_many through size validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I work on a booking application, where each `Home` can have several `Phone`.
I would like to limit the number of `Phone` by `Home` to 3, and display a nice error in the create phone form.

How can I achieve that, in a rails way ?

---

### code

```rb
class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :number, phone: true

  # validates_associated :homes_phones

  has_many :homes_phones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :homes, through: :homes_phones

end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class HomesPhone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home
  belongs_to :phone
  validate :check_phones_limit

  def check_phones_limit
    errors.add(:base, "too_many_phones") if home.phones.size >= 3
  end

end
```

---

### specs

```rb
  it 'should limit phones to 3' do
    user = create(:user)
    home = create(:home, :active, manager: user)
    expect(home.phones.create(user: user, number: "+33611223344")).to be_valid
    expect(home.phones.create(user: user, number: "+33611223345")).to be_valid
    expect(home.phones.create(user: user, number: "+33611223346")).to be_valid

    # unexpectedly raises a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    expect(home.phones.create(user: user, number: "+33611223347")).to be_invalid
  end
```

---

### Side notes

My understanding of the flow is:

- a transaction opens
- phone attributes are validated (and valid)
- phone is created, a primary key is available
- homes_phone is `saved!` and an error is raised because the validation fails
- the all transaction is rolled back, and the error bubble up

I have tried:

- `has_many before_add` in `Home` which also raise an error;
- validating these rules in `Phone` does not make sense to me, as this rule is a `Home` concern

Comment: I am not too sure what is your question. Though what seems strange is that in your Spec you are creating phones from the Home model `home.phones.create` whereas phones are children of `User`. I would rather expect the users to be able to create phones. Also your custom validator `check_phones_limit` seems to correctly enforce only 3 `HomePhone`s

Comment: Indeed users can have many phones. And they can decide what phone they want to attach to some homes they manage (hence the `homes_phones`). Is there anything else I can clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just validate it in the controller, count the phones and render a flash error, before you actually try and save the records.
Doing this in callbacks is difficult and not foolproof.

---

I've added some quick tests to cover different ways phones can be created:

```rb
# spec/models/homes_phone_spec.rb

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe HomesPhone, type: :model do
  it "saves 3 new phones" do
    home = Home.create(phones: 3.times.map { Phone.new })
    expect(home.phones.count).to eq 3
  end

  it "doesn't save 4 new phones" do
    home = Home.create(phones: 4.times.map { Phone.new })
    expect(home.phones.count).to eq 0
    expect(home.phones.size).to eq 4
  end

  it "can create up to 3 three phones through association" do
    home = Home.create!
    expect do
      5.times { home.phones.create }
    end.to change(home.phones, :count).by(3)
  end

  it "doesn't add 4th phone to existing record" do
    Home.create(phones: 3.times.map { Phone.new })
    home = Home.last

    # NOTE: every time you call `valid?` or `validate`, it runs validations 
    #       again and all previous errors are cleared.
    # expect(home.phones.create).to be_invalid
    
    expect(home.phones.create).to be_new_record
    # or
    # expect(home.phones.create).not_to be_persisted
    # expect(home.phones.create.errors.any?).to be true
  end

  it "adds phone limit validation error to Phone" do
    home = Home.create(phones: 3.times.map { Phone.new })
    phone = home.phones.create
    expect(phone.errors[:base]).to eq ["too many phones"]
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/phone.rb
class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :homes_phones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :homes, through: :homes_phones
end

# app/models/home.rb
class Home < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :homes_phones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :phones, through: :homes_phones
end
```

```rb
# app/models/homes_phone.rb
class HomesPhone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home
  # NOTE: setting `inverse_of` option will stop raising errors and
  #       just return `phone` with errors that we'll add below
  belongs_to :phone, inverse_of: :homes_phones

  # because of the way through association is saved with `save!` call
  # it raises validation errors. `inverse_of` allows the through association
  # to be properly built and it skips `save!` call:
  # https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L79-L80

  validate do
    # NOTE: if you use `homes_phones` association, the `size` method returns
    #       current count, instead of a lagging `phones.size` count.
    if home.homes_phones.size > 3
      errors.add(:base, "too many phones")
      phone.errors.merge!(errors)
    end
  end
end
```

```bash
$ rspec spec/models/homes_phone_spec.rb

HomesPhone
  saves 3 new phones
  doesn't save 4 new phones
  can create up to 3 three phones through association
  doesn't add 4th phone to existing record
  adds phone limit validation to Phone

Finished in 0.10967 seconds (files took 2.35 seconds to load)
5 examples, 0 failures
```

---

But it doesn't cover everything, like this:

```rb
it "can append up to 3 three phones" do
  home = Home.create!
  expect do
    5.times { home.phones << Phone.new }
  end.to change(home.phones, :count).by(3)
end
```

```bash
$ rspec spec/models/homes_phone_spec.rb:38
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/homes_phone_spec.rb"=>[38]}}

HomesPhone
  can append up to 3 three phones (FAILED - 1)
```

and I thought I fixed everything. You can try this instead:

```rb
after_validation do
  if home.homes_phones.size > 3
    errors.add(:base, "too many phones")
    phone.errors.merge! errors
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

```bash
$ rspec spec/models/homes_phone_spec.rb -f p
......

Finished in 0.12411 seconds (files took 2.25 seconds to load)
6 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Very informative answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the rails way of doing this, in your Home class

```
validates :phones, length: { maximum: 3, message: "too many phones" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could think validation is something like this: it target to the `Model` we want to create directly.

In your case, you want to validate when create `phones`, so you have to put the validation rule into the `Phone` model.

This way the validation will take effect, and you could get the error message correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see 2 pitfalls with your solution: when validating a phone, I can access the phone, but not the home. Besides, in my opinion, validity of a model should only depend on intrinsic characteristics: phone does not need to "know" about "homes"